# C# LINQ merging list and dictionary into new dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have the following code and it is working

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUsersWithFax(List<int> userIds)
        {
            Dictionary<int,Address> userAddresses = await _service.GetUserAddresses(userIds);
            Dictionary<int, bool> usersHaveFax = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            foreach (var userId in userIds)
            {
                usersHaveFax.Add(userId,
                    userAddresses.ContainsKey(userId) &&
                    userAddresses[userId].HasFax());
            }
            return usersHaveFax;
        }
```

However, I am looking for a more `linq` way to implement this. 
The algorithm is the following

1. Map one dictionary to another
2. Add missing keys with the default bool value (false)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Tuco just wondering how to improve my code

Comment: You can use `ToDictionary()`, but I don't see any advantages vs what your currently have in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
usersIds.ToDictionary(v => v, v => userAddresses.ContainsKey(v) && userAddresses[v].HasFax())
```